# Is a ternary expression possible for this construct?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if the following statement is possible to write as one line (i.e., [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) form).

```
if (A == B)
    FunctionA();
else
    FunctionB();
```

Both FunctionA and FunctionB are type *void*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. The conditional operator is only valid for *non-void* expressions. The point is to evaluate one of two expressions, and for that to be the result.

Basically: write the `if` statement. It's the idiomatic way of executing one *action* or another.

You *could* write an extension method like this:

```
// For demonstration purposes only. Please don't use in real life.
public static void Conditional(this bool result,
                               Action trueAction,
                               Action falseAction)
{
    Action action = result ? trueAction : falseAction;
    action();
}
```

Then:

```
(A == B).Conditional(FunctionA, FunctionB);
```

... but I'd *strongly* advise you not to.

Comment: The `if` - `else` form could run much faster.

Comment: @AlvinWong: Probably. More importantly, it would be *much* cleaner.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow, what a truly terrifying use of extension methods. A boolean method that conditionally executes one method or another....  Pandora called; she wants her evil back.

Comment: The point is to evaluate one of two expressions, and for that to be the result in many many other languages, yet they still allow it to be called in void context.

Comment: @ikegami: Different languages are allowed to handle different constructs differently. This would be reasonable in a language like F# where the Unit type isn't so different from other types, it just represents no information... but banning it works perfectly well in C# and Java with their similar approach to `void`.

Comment: Of course. I only showed that the explanation doesn't explain anything. I didn't say anything about what C# can or should do.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes it does - in the context of C#. Just because the same explanation doesn't apply to other languages doesn't in any way reduce its applicability within the context of C#.

Comment: I don't see it. What part of "The point is to evaluate one of two expressions, and for that to be the result" is context sensitive? All those terms have the same definition for every language I know. // 
Your explanation is lacking. Your conclusion doesn't follow from your premise. I've already shown that.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks for quoting just a single sentence as if that's the entire answer. I think we'll have to agree to disagree with the validity of my answer - if you've got a better answer yourself, I suggest you post it.

Comment: I didn't say the answer is wrong, I said the explanation isn't one. I don't know the reason it's the way it is even after reading your answer.

Comment: I mean; if anybody's got a problem with the extension-ness of it, just make it not an extension... drop the `this` and call as `Conditional(A == B, FunctionA, FunctionB)`. Not that hard.

Answer (score 14):

> if the following statement is possible to write as one line

Sure:

```
if (A == B) FunctionA(); else FunctionB();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, use the `if` statement.

However, by casting the two `void` functions to `Action`, this hack is possible:

```
(A == B ? (Action)FunctionA : FunctionB).Invoke();
```

This is especially handy when used in expression body `=>` methods because `if` can't be used there.

Of course: don't do that in serious projects!

Comment: It's not a hack; it satisfies the language rules. Btw you can drop `.Invoke`, like `(A == B ? (Action)FunctionA : FunctionB)()`. +1, PS I can't really think of any particular reason not to do it in a "serious" (?) project ‍♂️.