# Conditional C# Ternary Operator statement to execute methods with Void Return Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

How can we use coalescing Operator to choose method calls depending upon true or false value , as follows:

1. Request.QueryString=="new"? NewPage() : OldPage() ;
2. Request.QueryString=="Black"? BlackMonie(): Request.QueySTring=="White"? WhiteMonie():Tacs();

instead of the common coalescing operator call using stoage variable as follows:
string s= color=="r"? "Red" : "Green";

Comment: You are asking about the "ternary" operator. `??` is the coalescing operator.

Comment: That's not a coalesce operator, it's a conditional operator.

Comment: yes, it should have been Ternary operator/conditional operator. thanks GrantWinney and Enigmativity and all who corrected me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary Expression Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959410/ternary-expression-possible)

Answer (score 4):

It's not overly clear from your question, but I assume that `NewPage()` and `OldPage()` are both `void` methods.

So, you can't use the ternary operator like you're proposing without getting into a lot of messy code that returns actions that then need to be invoked.

And there seems to be little benefit in trying to get this to work as the built in `if`, `else` keywords are pretty close to what you want.

Here are your suggested use of the `?:` operator with the standard `if` code:

```
Request.QueryString == "new" ? NewPage() : OldPage();
if (Request.QueryString == "new") NewPage(); else OldPage();
```

That's 7 characters difference.

I'd stick with the standard `if` approach.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* assign those methods to an appropriate delegate type, and then invoke the delegate:

```
var someCall = Request.QueryString=="new" ? new Action(NewPage) : new Action(OldPage);
someCall();
```

but you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a correct syntax in your ternary operator statement, like in the following sample (see MSDN ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
string _test = (Request.QueryString=="new")? NewPage() : OldPage() ;
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,